# Importing from Business Contact Manager to Access

Tags: ms-access, outlook

Is there a way to import the database that is created for Microsoft Outlook with Business Contact Manager to an Access 2007 database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it uses SQL Server Express (I haven't tried since Outlook 2003). You may want to see if you can import the db tables.

Comment: I can confirmn that it (BCM 2007) does indeed use SQL Server Express by default, and usually its own named instance.